# Is it possible to connect to Metatrader enabled forex without Metatrader client application?

Tags: ruby, node.js, metatrader4, forex

Isn't it possible to connect to various forex brokers, using Metatrader 4/5 Api?

And I'm not talking about connecting to Metatrader client application, like this nodejs plugins allows https://github.com/PenguinTraders/MT4-Node.js/tree/master.

I'm talking about native connect -  directly to forex Brooker, that has Metatrader enabled, so it's possible to make trader apps/robots in any language, like nodejs and ruby, and even hosted on servers?

I mean, can't one use fireshark, to find out the Api?

Comment: It is possible only if you have manager or administrator access. Apart from that, there is no other official way to do that.

Comment: What do you mean, by "manager or administrator access"? You mean login credentials of the forex Brooker? Or something else?

Comment: Yes, you have to have broken credentials, not trader

Comment: Can you point me in the right direction, on how I can get more specific API u can use? I have no problem creating apps that connect to external api's, but I can't seem to find any resources on that..

Comment: If you have broker license, MQ will give you access to their private portal with api documentation

Comment: Okey, you misunderstood me.. Most brokers use Mt4. I want to create an app that uses Mt4 API.. So the Brooker thinks I'm connecting using Mt4, when in reality it's my custom app.

Comment: As I said MQ has API, but it only from brokers. There is no official way to simulate MT4